# iOS - App Rejected Because Of Guideline 2.10 - Resolution For iPad - How to Fix?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard

My iPhone only app has been rejected for the following reason provided by Apple:

> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines.

I now understand that the iPad has its own iPhone simulator that you can run iPhone apps on. After initial debugging, I noticed that, when testing on the iPad Air (iOS 9.0), my iPhone 5 storyboard is being used in its own iPhone simulator.

This is how it looks (correctly) on the iPhone 5:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMHyx.png

And this is how it looks (incorrectly) on the iPad:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PHG4.png

Since the iPad is using my iPhone 5 storyboard, why isn't it scaling everything correctly? How do I fix this?

*****EDIT*****

I have discovered that I made a mistake when debugging and the iPad's iPhone simulator has a display height of 480, which is the size of an iPhone 4. My code below was causing my iPhone 6+ storyboard to be shown:

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

//get the right storyboard for the device.
if(result.height == 568)
{
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"IPHONE 5 STORYBOARD!");
}
else if(result.height == 667)
{
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"IPHONE 6 STORYBOARD!");
}
else //iPhone 6+
{
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6Plus" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"IPHONE 6+ STORYBOARD!");
}
```

However, I thought I made my app for only iPhone 5 and up by setting it to iOS 8 and up, meaning that I don't have an iPhone 4 storyboard. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible otherwise to restrict your app on a per device basis. Since your app is iOS 8 and up, you will have to support iPhone 4S's resolution. Since iPhone 4S is getting iOS 9 too, you will have to support it in the near future too.

Comment: I was thinking about putting "metal" in my info.plist under the "Required Device Capabilities" since Metal is only supported by iPhone 5 and up. I got that info from this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1

Comment: Will that get my app rejected since I'm listing "metal" as a requirement but my app isn't using it?

Comment: Okay, well I guess I have no choice but to go through the hardship of making an iPhone 4 storyboard. I marked this as the answer because it gave the the "why" in saying that iPhone 4s still had the latest iOS (I didn't know that). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

iPad always presents a view size equal to iPhone 4S or lower when you run iPhone app in iPad. So try to change your app in such a way that your app should work properly with iPhone 4 simulator or device.

Comment: Does that mean I have no choice but to make a storyboard for the iPhone 4? My app is supposed to only be for iPhone 5 and up. :(

Comment: You have to provide support for screen resolution < 568 also.

Answer (score 0):

You solve the problem by either supporting the iPad properly (have an iPhone + iPad application), or by supplying a storyboard for 3.5 inch - alternatively, using the 4 inch storyboard, using layout constraints properly, and perhaps adjusting some properties.

The obvious change for picking the right storyboard is to change: if (height <= 568) .. else if (height <= 667) ... else ... Your code says that everything that isn't 568 or 667 pixels high is a 6+, which as you can see is nonsense.

You could also just support the iPad and use the 6+ storyboard for the iPad. Again, using layout constraints properly.